# Trapezoidal rule - Multivariable

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

If I wanted to integrate the function $f(x,y)$ over the region $[a,b]\times[c,d]$ with two segments, am I going about this the right way?

$$I(f) = \int_a^b \int_c^d f(x,y)\ dy\,dx = \int_a^b g(x) \ dx $$

where $g(x) = \int_c^d f(x,y) \ dy$

Using the formula for the trapezoidal rule for single variable functions, and extending it to $g(x)$, letting $h = \frac{b-a}{2}$ and $m = \frac{a+b}{2}$:

$$I(f) = \frac{h}{2} [g(a) + 2g(m) + g(b)]$$

$$I(f) = \frac{h}{2}\left[ \int_c^d f(a,y)\ dy + \int_c^d f(m,y)\ dy + \int_c^d f(b,y)\ dy\right]. $$

Is this right?

Comment: I changed $[a,b]$x$[c,d]$ to $[a,b]\times[c,d]$.  Some day I might suspect that some people don't realize that MathJax codes mathematical notation the way TeX does, and TeX was designed for this sort of thing. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @ekudamram: Did you mean Composite Trapezoidal?

Comment: @Amzoti: I did, have I made a mistake?

Comment: @ekudamram: Section 4: https://www.kth.se/social/upload/52a04c17f27654620e188bb0/Ant-Integration.pdf, or see: http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/~jmahaffy/courses/s10/math541/lectures/pdf/week09/lecture.pdf . If you post an example, it can be worked to show the details.

Comment: Excellent, that makes sense now - I didn't go far enough with my formula, as it appears I only calculated my integrals in one direction

Comment: I have found this: http://www.math.usm.edu/lambers/mat460/fall09/lecture32.pdf
The example on page 2 explains the method well, and couple with the links you posted I can see how it works

Comment: It does raise one theory question for me though, we have the Trapezoidal Rule for single variables and also the Composite Trapezoidal Rule for single variables, but when working with multivariable functions, there is only mention of the Composite Trapezoidal Rule - is this the only rule that exists for multivariable functions?

Comment: You will also find Composite Simpson's. The reason is that you want the best accuracy you can get - so why bother with the other less accurate methods (you certainly can). Also, you go to methods like Monte Carlo Simulation for those (much easier).